# How to convert chunck by chunck byte array into base64 string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, base64, arrays, chunks

We are reading byte array of a file and converting it into base64 string as follows

```
    public static string ZipToBase64()
            {
                FileUpload fileCONTENT = FindControl("FileUploadControl") as FileUpload;

                byte[] byteArr = fileCONTENT.FileBytes;

                return Convert.ToBase64String(byteArr);

            }

    string attachmentBytes = ZipToBase64();
    string json1 = "{ \"fileName\": \"Ch01.pdf\", \"data\": " + "\"" + attachmentBytes + "\"}";
```

When we try to convert large file upto 1 GB into base64 string, it is throwing out of memory exception. We are sending this json to restful wcf service. Following is my method in RESTful WCF Service.

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public void UploadFile1(Stream input)
        {

            string UserName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["UserName"];
            string Password = Sql.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Password"]);
            string sDevideID = Sql.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["DeviceID"]);
            string Version = string.Empty;
            if (validateUser(UserName, Password, Version, sDevideID) == Guid.Empty)
            {
                SplendidError.SystemWarning(new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0), "Invalid username or password for " + UserName);
                throw (new Exception("Invalid username or password for " + UserName));
            }


            string sRequest = String.Empty;
            using (StreamReader stmRequest = new StreamReader(input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                sRequest = stmRequest.ReadToEnd();
            }
            // http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/07/23/javascriptserializer-dictionary-to-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx

            JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            // 12/12/2014 Paul.  No reason to limit the Json result. 
            json.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = json.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(sRequest);
            string base64String = dict["data"];
            string fileName = dict["fileName"];


            byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);

            //FileStream fs1 = stream as FileStream;

            string networkPath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NetWorkPath"];
            File.WriteAllBytes(networkPath + "/" + fileName, fileBytes); // Requires System.IO
        }
```

Please provide solution for converting large byte array into base64 string

Comment: Sending 1GB base64-encoded string as json is not a very good idea, don't you think?

Comment: @Evk Thanks for comment. We are using android mobile applications and web applications to upload file. We are uploading file on a remote server on file system. Thats why I have written RESTFul wcf service for uploading file

Comment: But I mean - if your files are big (more than say 10MB) - you should never pass them serialized in json. You have to pass them in request body in a streamed manner. This is  true for RESTful wcf services too. I could have shown how to convert byte[] chunk by chunk to base64 but that would _not_ help you.

Comment: @Evk Yes we are on same page. I have passed the json in a streamed manner to WCF Service. I have updated my question. Please see. Please provide solution for converting byte array chunk by chunk in base64 string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact you use Stream input in your wcf service does not really mean you pass anything in streamed manner. In fact in your case you do not, because:

1. You buffer whole file on client in memory to build json string.
2. You buffer whole file on server in memory via `stmRequest.ReadToEnd()`.

So no streaming takes place. First you should realize that no json is needed here - you just need to pass file in your http request body. What you should do first is throw away all code below security checks in your `UploadFile1` method and instead do this:

```
public void UploadFile1(string fileName, Stream input) {
    // check your security headers here
    string networkPath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NetWorkPath"];
    using (var fs = File.Create(networkPath + "/" + fileName)) {
        input.CopyTo(fs);
    }
}
```

Here we just copy input stream to output stream (file) without any buffering (of course `CopyTo` will buffer chunks but they will be very small). Mark your service method with:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/UploadFile1/{fileName}")]
```

To allow you pass filename in query string.

Now to client. Not sure which method you use to communicate with server, I'll show example with raw HttpWebRequest.

```
var filePath = "path to your zip file here";
var file = new FileInfo(filePath);
// pass file name in query string
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://YourServiceUrl/UploadFile1/" + file.Name);            
request.Method = "POST";
// set content length
request.ContentLength = file.Length;
// stream file to server
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(file.FullName)) {
    using (var body = request.GetRequestStream()) {
         fs.CopyTo(body);
    }
}
// ensure no errors
request.GetResponse().Dispose();
```

Comment: I am getting error in compiling wcf service. Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'.

Comment: See here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/justinjsmith/2008/02/15/enablewebscript-uritemplate-and-http-methods/. If nothing helps - pass filename in header instead of query string. I actually hate WCF because of those tiny little problems appearing everywhere and did not use it for years already (and never looked back).

Comment: I have passed the filename in header.

Comment: I was also able to upload large files now. I was getting timeout exception sometimes at request.GetRequestStream and sometimes at  fs.CopyTo(body) when I tried to upload files greater than 500 MB. Then I have followed this link http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2014/01/14/tackling-timeout-issues-when-uploading-large-files-with-httpwebrequest/ Now everything is working fine.

Comment: Thanks @Evk. You have helped me a lot

Comment: @ShaileshJaiswal you are welcome. Don't forget to mark answers that helped you as, well, answers:)